# How can I right-align two divs in a Bootstrap column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How could I right align two DIVs, and their content staying stacked, within a column contained in a row?

An image of what I'm trying to roughly accomplish is below:
[image: Sketch what what I'm trying to accomplish]

A sample codeply can be found [here](https://www.codeply.com/p/HBapK6zmrL) that contains the HTML and CSS below. [This](https://www.codeply.com/p/qOYy5H3N6I) codeply forked from the original gets me close, but doesn't keep the content stacked, nor keeps the content middle aligned.

With the HTML and CSS below I've tried adding `d-flex` and `flex-row` onto the `col-sm-4` DIVs, but that doesn't allow the content within the children DIVs to stay stacked and I'm unable to right align the child elements. Also the middle alignment is lost. I've also tried containing everything within DIV 1 and 2 in parent DIVs and doing `d-flex` with `justifiy-content-end`. That also isn't accomplishing what I'm looking for.

```css
.main-container{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height:100px;
}

.clickable-link {
    font-size:10px;
}

.content-section-one {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid main-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- DIV #1 -->
            <div class="content-section-one">
                <div>
                    <span><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                    <span>Some Text Here</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- DIV #2 -->
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
                    <span>Some More Text Here</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>A Completely Separate Section</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CuteCodeRob, if I understand correctly, you're saying to move out the divs and have them be main level columns? My issue at that point is spacing. The content for the spans could grow or shrink, it'd be nice to have that dynamic and not confined to a, say, col-2 sizing, if that makes sense.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob, answers go down there. You short-circuit the SO process by posting them as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at some of your parameters, but a nested row with columns set to not grow seems to work. Notice the `text-nowrap` class on some of the text elements.

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: 100px;
}

.clickable-link {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.content-section-one {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid main-container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row justify-content-left">
        <div class="col flex-grow-0 text-right">
          <div>
            <span><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>
            <span class="text-nowrap">Some Text Here</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col flex-grow-0 text-right border-right border-dark">
          <div>
            <span><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
            <spann class="text-nowrap">Some More Text Here</span>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>A Completely Separate Section</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this and cheng it in your local

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
<div class="row justify-content-end align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <!-- DIV #1 -->
        <div class="content-section-one">
            <div>
                <span><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                <span>Some Text Here</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- DIV #2 -->
        <div>
            <div>
                <span><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
                <span>Some More Text Here</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="clickable-link" href="#">Clickable Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 bg-danger">
        <p>A Completely Separate Section</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `flex-row-reverse` changes the order. I suppose I could also switch the order of the divs in the HTML, but the issue of having the clickable link text right aligned is still present.